# Func<> add an extra parameter dynamically

Tags: c#

how can I add an extra parameter to my `Func<>` expression ? Something like:

```
Func<char, bool> myPredicate = (x) => (char.IsLetter(x) || x == 'X');

...

"abc".All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || myPredicate);
```

but I get an error

**Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and Func< char, bool>**

Comment: You need to invoke the func.

Comment: Another option is to create a new predicate first `Func<char,bool> isLetterOrDigit = x => myPredicate(x) || char.IsDigit(x);` then `"abc".All(isLetterOrDigit);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to invoke the `myPredicate` function like this:

```
"abc".All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || myPredicate(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, what about this other approach?

```
var text = "abc";

var predicates = new Func<char, bool>[] { 
    x => char.IsLetter(x) || x == 'X', 
    char.IsDigit 
};

var result = predicates.Any(text.All);

// Outputs TRUE 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Also, if you need to check many specific characters, you can create a `charEquals` with curried parameters:

```
var text = "abc";

// More type inference to generalize charEquals to just equals, please!
Func<char, Func<char, bool>> charEquals = ca => cb => ca == cb;

var predicates = new Func<char, bool>[] { 
    char.IsLetter, 
    charEquals('X'),
    charEquals('Y'),
    charEquals('Z'),
    char.IsDigit 
};

var result = predicates.Any(text.All);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```